# Rspec 3.0.0.beta2 with Guard in Rails 3.2.17

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, guard

Trying to configure Guard with Rspec 3.0.0.beta2. When running guard I get the following error:

"Guard::RSpec failed to achieve its , exception was: .... NoMethodError: undefined method `parse_options' for #

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the correct version of rspec, rspec-rails, and guard-rspec worked for me, do a gem list rspec, gem list guard to make sure you have the most up to date versions of each of the gems.

Addressed in issue #251 of guard-rspec on github: https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/251

```
#relevant section of Gemfile

group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.2.7'  #, require: false
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0.0.beta2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta2'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your Guard version, guard-rspec version etc.

Please follow the [gard-rspec guidelines for reporting an issue](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) (and don't hesitate to [report directly in guard-rspec's issue tracker](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/new).